Is it possible to calculate RSA public exponent when we have Private key?
I have RSA d (private exponent) that is 0x10001 and n (modulus).
As I understand, n is common between Private and Public keys.
Now I need to calculate e (public exponent), is it possible?
I also tried Yafu, but no result..

I'm willing to bet that 0x10001 is the public exponent e and not the private exponent d.

@Siguza You're wrong, as I already wrote, it's private exponent (d) because I use that for decrypting data and it's ok.

That just sounds like you're looking at signatures rather than encryption.

In no real life scenario 0x10001 is a private exponent.

@bereal Do you mean it can't be?? I said I can decrypt data using this as d !!

@MasoudRev from the pure math point of view, it can, because it's enough that e*d = 1 mod phi(N). But in real cases, e is quite often 0x10001 (that makes computations faster), and d is expected to be large, otherwise, Wiener's attack becomes possible. Those facts put together make me quite sure that what you have was intended as a public key.

You seem to assume that you have the private key - but you don't. And thus, what you're asking isn't possible.
First, I'm willing to bet that your 0x10001 is actually the public exponent e and not the private exponent d, just judging from experience. And if you're "decrypting" with it, that just sounds like you're using the public key to verify a signature.
But it doesn't matter, from a mathematical perspective those are one and the same. d and e are each other's exponential inverse modulo n, so if you could get e from d, then the same process could be applied to get d from e, which would break RSA.
The only known and computationally feasible way to compute the exponential inverse of a number modulo n = p*q is to find its multiplicative inverse modulo λ(n) = lcm(p-1, q-1)... which requires you to know p and q.
